# C# Read large zip archive from non-seekable stream

Tags: c#, .net-core, zip

I've got a zip file provided in a stream that is not seekable.
The zip file itself has a size greater than `Int32.MaxValue`. My goal is to read one of the entries contained in the zip file and output it to some target stream.
Similar to this:

```
using var cs = new System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream (...);
using var z = new System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive (cs, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
var entry = zip.GetEntry("1");
entry.Open().CopyTo(...);
```

Because the stream does not support seeking, the `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive` class tries to copy the stream into a backing `MemoryStream`. This fails because a `MemoryStream` has a size limit of 2GB and raises an `IOException`:

> Stream was too long.

I would like to avoid downloading the entire stream into a file before reading the entry. Is there a way to do this? Using other libraries is fine with me.

It is possible to read the stream twice or thrice. My hope is that this suffices to locate the entry content so it can be decompressed.

Comment: Wouldn't `ZLibStream` be an answer? This stream seems to support seeking.

Comment: Sadly not - `ZLibStream` refers to the compressed content. But I cannot even open a `ZipArchive`, the constructor already throws.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I find it strange that ZLibStream doesn't support having the stream passed in the constructor be the output for decompression and the ZLibStream be the input for compressed data in blocks. And why can't the stream passed in the contructor not be the input for decompressed data and the ZLibstream be the output for compressed data. Looking at old repo for Ionic ZLibStream it seems like it was able to work in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library appears to be what you (we) need:
https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress

From their readme.md:

> The major feature is support for non-seekable streams so large files
> can be processed on the fly (i.e. download stream).

Note that another option would be to use Pipelines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines

I ended up using the standard deflate library. I think it would be best to use pipelines with either library you choose, probably zlibstream with pipelines would work.

Comment: Have not tried it myself yet, but that seems to be the perfect solution.

Comment: I just gave it a test-drive and it seems to work as expected, at least for Deflate. The API is a bit weird and seems to not be consistent between compression algorithms.